# How do i call Partial View From UI End mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

i have this code on index when i click on it i want to call edit partial form and pass parameter

```
    if (e.item.name == "btnHeaderCreatePassword") {

        var index = UsersGrid.GetFocusedRowIndex();
        // Call partial view from controller
    }
```

My controller

```
    public ActionResult EditHeaderFormPartial(string ObjId)
    {

        var user = db.Users.Where(c=>c.Id == ObjId).SingleOrDefault();

        if (user == null)
        {
            ViewData["isEdit"] = false;
            return PartialView("UsersEditPartialFormView", new User());
        }

        ViewData["isEdit"] = true;
        return PartialView("UsersEditPartialFormView", user);

    }
```

the aim is to call EditHeaderFormPartial from clicking btnHeaderCreatePassword as a popup

Comment: You need to write `return EditHeaderFormPartial(in mid);` in the if block

Answer (score 0):

In your main view take a div (where you need to load the partial view)

```
<div id="loadpartialview"></div>
```

Now write an ajax

```
$("#btnclick").click(function () {
   path =  "/controller/Actionmethod";
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: path,
    success: function (dataval) {
        $('#loadpartialview').html(dataval);
    }
});
   } else {
       alert("Field Empty");
     }
});
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

UsersEditPartialFormView is the form i want to call with input and i would like to pass ObjId at this point i get null object ID from the UI

```
    public ActionResult changepassword(string ObjId)
    {

        var user = db.Users.Where(c => c.Id == ObjId).SingleOrDefault();

        if (user == null)
        {
            ViewData["isEdit"] = false;
            return PartialView("UsersEditPartialFormView", new User());
        }

        ViewData["isEdit"] = true;
        return PartialView("UsersEditPartialFormView", user);


    }
```

so when the btnHeaderCreatePassword is clicked i get the value of selected row
and call the ajax method as below

```
    if (e.item.name == "btnHeaderCreatePassword") {

        var index = UsersGrid.GetFocusedRowIndex();

        $.ajax({
            dataType: "html",
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("changepassword", "users")',
            cache: false,
            data: { userId: userId },
            success: function (data) {
                // UsersGrid.Refresh();
               $('#UsersEditPartialFormView').html(dataval);
             //   alert("Got you");
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Request Status: ' + xhr.status + '; Status Text: ' + textStatus + '; Error: ' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
```